# Price of Amazon CloudFront vs dedicated server?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-aws

I am trying to estimate my monthly bill for Amazon CloudFront.

Let's say I need 1'000 GB/month transfer. The price calculator give me a bill of $120.

That's totally overpriced. If I buy a dedicated server I can have for the same price 10'000GB/month and more.

Am I doing something wrong?

http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/calc5.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The advantage of CloudFront is that it serves your content geographically near to your users. A dedicated server is only in one location, but enables you to do lots of different things. You can't easily compare the two things.

Comment: so basically that's a normal price? Wow...

Comment: I need at least 4000,5000 GB/month. That would cost me like 400/500USD/month--- that's just crazy

Comment: That's only crazy if you're not generating revenue from the website, if you already have an existing website with visitors you should be trying to generate some money from them to offset the cost of your servers.

Comment: You can also check your local ISP see if they have any higher plans for more bandwidth they are usually pretty cheap and come with a dedicated IP or a few sometimes. Then you can host your own server again until you're making money.

Comment: I found this site which has CDNs listed. http://www.cdnplanet.com. Not many have pricing, but BitGravity was $150 per Tb, so CloudFront is cheaper.

Comment: For example... Take this SP Mini 2012: http://www.ovh.co.uk/dedicated_servers/superplan_mini.xml with 60EUR/month you can transfer like 10'000 GB/month. With cloud that would cost me like 2000EUR/month.... LOL ? This price doesnt' justify geo targeting of a cdn

Comment: A significant advantage of CloudFront comes when you're fronting something slow, like AWS S3. At that point you're paying for speed, rather than dedicated "hosting".